# Determine if rows are filtered by user

Tags: excel, delphi

I have written an Excel plugin.  Everything is working fine, up to a point.  Assume I am iterating through all rows, doing some work... The user may have enabled a filter, so that the current row is not visible due to that filter.  How do I determine what data should not be processed because it is not visible due to the filter?

Comment: [Hidden?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834657%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: @Sertac.  Your comment led me in the right direction.... Upvoted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision of the previous answer did not working for me, so I found another more simple solution by using *aSheet.Rows[RowNum].Hidden* property:

```
function IsRowVisible(aSheet: OLEVariant; aRowNum: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := not aSheet.Rows[aRowNum].Hidden;
end;
```

In this function *aSheet* - excel worksheet and *aRowNum* - row number. Same solution can be used for columns.

Answer (score 2):

Answer found.  There does not appear to be a row.filtered property.  There is a Hidden property, but it is on ranges, not rows.

Solution:  Build a range, based on entire row, then check Hidden property.

```
function IsRowVisible(RowNum: Integer): Boolean;
var
  FilterRange: OleVariant;
  RangeText: String;
begin
  RangeText := 'A' + IntToStr(RowNum);
  // aws is my activesheet
  FilterRange := aws.Range[RangeText, RangeText].EntireRow;
  Result := not(FilterRange.EntireRow.Hidden);
end;
```